# SignalR, Messages are to be pushed by the Server without any event triggered by the client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

There are running examples of SignalR, but in those, i have seen that the process is started by the client i.e. every piece of code contains following similar lines

```
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#mybutton').click(function () {
                    notifier.server.doLongOperation();
                });
            });
```

The process on server starts on **$('#mybutton').click** and then responds.

Is my understanding correct? If yes then is it possible to start the process by Server? I mean Server will push messages to all clients **without any triggering from the client side**.

This didn't work

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Broadcast>();
context.Clients.All.Send(message);
```

**My bad, method name on client side was incorrect. Problem solved**

Comment: there is no need also triggering event from other client. if a client starts the process the others will get notifications from server. Pls check client side error message, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to send server initiated "messages" from the server to clients. Note that you have to call a method on the client. Note that it's a RPC/Remoting type of communication.

On the server you'd have a code like this:

```
Clients.All.Say("Hello World!");
```

where the client needs to define a function:

```
myHub.client.say = function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

see the [SignalR documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromhub)